# Forcing English as default locale in Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony

I am struggling with the default locale options in Symfony 2.3. My app is supposed to be in English regardless of what the user's browser settings are.

Right now I am getting the validation messages of the form component in German (as I am using a German browser):

My configuration settings are:

```
//config.yml
framework:
  translator:      { fallback: en }
  default_locale:  en


// parameters.yml
locale: en

// base.html.twig
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
...
```

**Edit**

One solution is to add custom html5 validation messages to the form element. Are there other options?

```
$builder->add('pname', 'text', array(
                "label" => "Internal name:",
                "required" => true,
                "attr" => array(
                    'class' => 'input-xxlarge required',
                    'oninvalid'=> "setCustomValidity('Please do this and that ')"
                )
            )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//parameters.yml
parameters:
    ......
    locale: en
```

Comment: Ilost a "e" ...     The configuration in app/config/parameters.yml

Comment: Yes, this is set, too. I got it probably wrong: The error messages are html5 error messages. So the browser is checking, symfony is not involved and the only solution is to add custom html5 error messages as outlined in my question's edit section.

Comment: can you list your twig templating coding

Comment: you mean <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

Comment: The word need be translated.Are you use {{ 'error message' |trans}} ?

Answer (score 0):

in file parameters.yml

```
parameters:
    locale: en
```

Comment: Yes, this is set, too. I got it probably wrong: The error messages are html5 error messages. So the browser is checking, symfony is not involved and the only solution is to add custom html5 error messages as outlined in my question's edit section.